# $r$ successes contained in a set of $s$ trials in a sequence of $n$ Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability

Considering a sequence of $n$ Bernoulli trials, I'm looking for the probability to obtain at least $r$ consecutive successes within a set of $s$ trials. Meaning, there must be at most $s - 2$ trials between the $1$st and $r$th successes for them to be taken into account.

For example, $p = \cfrac{1}{600}$, $n=216$, $s=36$ and $r=6$

Thank you!

Comment: Must the $r$ sucesses be within the $s$ trials, or must there be a part of $s$ trials containing $r$ CONSECUTIVE sucesses ?

Comment: The r successes do not have to be consecutive, they just have to be contained in a set of trials of length s